# Error on Azure Login via CLI, but everything works

Tags: azure, entra-id

After login via the CLI to Microsoft Azure I receive the following error.

> Failed to authenticate '{'additional_properties': {}, 'id':
>   '/tenants/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'tenant_id':
>   'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'}' due to error 'Get Token
>   request returned http error: 400 and server response:
>   {"error":"interaction_required","error_description":"AADSTS50076: Due
>   to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you
>   moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to
>   access 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'. Trace ID:
>   xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx Correlation ID:
>   xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx Timestamp: 2019-11-26
>   12:38:30Z","error_codes":[50076],"timestamp":"2019-11-26
>   12:38:30Z","trace_id":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","correlation_id":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50076","suberror":"basic_action"}'

Yet I'm still able to fully use Azure without any further issues.

I've checked AAD (Azure Active Directory) and MFA isn't active on our tenant. Also I checked AAD about the possible location change mentioned in the error message, but couldn't find anything.

How do I fix the error / what needs to be configured in AAD?

Comment: if you login to the portal, does it ask for MFA?

Comment: No it doesn‘t ask for MFA. Not at azure-cli browser auth and not on portal.azure.com

Comment: it sounds like you account might have access to multiple tenant, one of them might be failing.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging into the portal manually first, using your default browser, complete the MFA process, keep the browser open, and then run the "az login" from the cli again.